# Does accepting an answer invalidate a Low Quality Post review task?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, accepted-answer, low-quality-posts

I have [encountered a post with a weird timeline](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/posts/21912/timeline):

13:19 - Answer was posted. 
13:20 - Answer was flagged as Very Low Quality. 
13:35 - A Low-Quality review task was created. 
13:36 - Answer was flagged as Not An Answer. 
13:39 - Answer was accepted. 
13:40 - Review task was invalidated. 
13:44 - Answer was flagged as Not An Answer. 
18:18 - Answer was edited, marking the Very Low Quality flag helpful.

The two Not An Answer flags are still pending, and now need a moderator to intervene. So I'm wondering, does accepting an answer invalidate a Low Quality review task?

Comment: I'd be interested, too, in questioning whether, for the mere fact of a quick acceptance of a low quality answer by an aske, ought not to exempt a post from the low quality queue.  But then again, any post in the low quality queue is removed immediately after *any edit to the post whatsoever.*  I suppose the "logic", if there is any logic to this, is that the low-quality post remains eligible for further downvotes/close votes/delete votes from community members, just not performed from the low-quality queue.

Comment: @Namaste I've been thinking about the same, but the only argument I can come up with here is 'the flags were valid, the post wasn't up to quality standards'. Accepting the answer did not mark any flags helpful, declined or disputed though, so it would be a question of 'do you want the community to be able to review this vs. do you always want a moderator to do this'. The community can even unofficially review accepted answers (in e.g. chat) and delete them if their score is 0 or less... it just won't go through the official queue, apparently. I need more time to think about this ;)

Comment: Understandable, @Tinkeringbell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it does. Any post which is closed, deleted, locked, or accepted is considered ineligible for the Low Quality Posts queue. For answers, the deleted and closed status of the parent question are also checked (which can cause a situation where if the question is locked, but the answer is not, the answer would still be ineligible).